# How secure is BLE for a door lock

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, locks, doors

I am interested in setting up a trigger that can unlock door locks using an iPhone. The lock and unlock mechanism is not an issue as I have an API end point for this once authorized it is more an issue around the trigger.

I have seen that in the wikipedia artical for iBeacons it says that these are not secure although some companies offer versions that change the UUID to prevent cloning. For this reason companies like paypal just use them as initial triggers.

Is it correct to say then locks such as this (https://9to5mac.com/2015/04/24/apple-watch-hotel-room-key/) are using a priority security mechanism and custom BLE rather than iBecons?

Comment: Blackhat.com pdf on gattacking BLE - might be a worthwhile read https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-16/materials/us-16-Jasek-GATTacking-Bluetooth-Smart-Devices-Introducing-a-New-BLE-Proxy-Tool-wp.pdf

Comment: Just don't do it. IoT locks are a bad idea https://media.ccc.de/v/33c3-8019-lockpicking_in_the_iot

Answer (score 1):

The security is not in the BLE technology, but in the way the company implements the solution.  Your best bet is to go with a door lock manufactured by a reputable security company that boasts a 3rd party vet the security of the device.